# Why is dd so slow on a NVMe SSD?

Tags: files, performance, dd, io

I recently watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zuwa8zlfXSY) and in it, the author explains that a ram disk is far faster than HDD/SSD when using `dd` command. I understand why this is the case. What I don't understand, however, is why I got a write speed of 220MB/s when I did his example command of `dd if=/dev/zero of=test.iso bs=1M count=8000` on a system with 16GB of RAM, a 12-core Ryzen 3600X CPU, and a NVMe SSD rated at up to 5GB/s write speeds.

I understand RAM will always be faster, but this seems so slow that there must be something else at play here. Is it the way that he was using the `dd` command? I don't know the internals of `dd` but is this a situation where the system is limiting the performance, or has the command just been misused?

*Note: After running the exact same command a second time in a row, the second write was much faster at 1.4GB/s, but this doesn't clear up confusion for me.*

Answer (score 7):

NAND flash media like SSDs have a minimum block erase size, which means that if you `dd` data on them with a smaller block size, the SSD controller has to erase blocks several times to write to positions within the block. If the minimum block erase size is 4M, 1M means the block has to be rewritten 4 times more than necessary. The SSD would need to erase the same 4M block 4 times.

The fact that it gets much faster the second time the same `dd` command is run can be explained by caching and internal optimization by kernel, driver and controller, similar to what you see when you repeat a `find` command.

I refer to the [excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/992088/375187) by @greg-kennedy for more information and a [script to find the minimum erase block size](https://github.com/bradfa/flashbench), which should be used as `dd`s block size value for optimum performance.

Sometimes, you can find it also in the specs of the device or by reading `/sys/class/mtd/mtdx/erasesize`, depending on the individual device.

Comment: Please explain how you calculate 'need to erase the same 4M block 500 times'.

Comment: If you write in a minimum erase block size of 4M a 8000 sized dd block, dd writes the first 8000 bytes, the controller has to erase 4M to rewrite. After that, for the next step, the second 8000 bytes from dd go in second position of the same 4M block, the controller has again to erase 4M. Repeat 498 times.
When you use a 4M block in dd to match, rewrite is done only once.

Comment: OP is using bs=1M and count=8000, not bs=8000

Comment: The `dd` block size is 1 M (mibibyte) and count is how many such blocks are written. If I understand correctly, the background tool, that writes to the drive is independent of the dd block size except if you force flushing the buffer after each block (with `oflag=dsync`). -- ninja'd by Oskar Skog ;-)

Comment: I confused the dd block size with the count. Corrected.

Comment: What I wrote is based on experience with small SBCs writing to flash media. Setting the dd block size to the minimum erase size speeds up significantly. No idea how it is actually implemented behind the scenes.

Comment: My experience is that the default block size 512 bytes makes `dd` itself slow. But I find [no significant speed difference with block size 4096 bytes (4K) and greater for typical USB flash media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931581/flashing-ubuntu-iso-to-usb-stick-with-dd-recommended-block-size/931588#931588). For the purpose of this question, I also tested block size 1 M and 4 M. There was no significant difference is write speed (when including flushing the buffers).

Comment: Interesting, but the program I linked to (flashbench, on GitHub) shows differences with the different block sizes in line with my answer. Could it be that you ran into a bottleneck during your tests over 4K block size?

Comment: I think that the bottleneck in the test of my link is the write speed of the target devices (or in some case of the USB 2 system). Anyway, the details differ between different usage cases. So we can expect that different bottlenecks may be limit the speed. Let us hope that our different approaches and this discussion can help the OP improve their write speed :-)

Comment: This answer is false.  If you write sequentially to an SSD in 8k chunks, it DOES NOT need to write in the 4MB erase block chunks.  An SSD must _erase_ in large blocks, but it can write sequentially in small chunks to those blocks.   Any NVMe controller in the last dozen years will re-order random writes and pack them into such blocks as well.

Answer (score 2):

I did some tests in my rather old workstation (Lenovo Thinkstation C30), where there is an NVME drive, a SATA-SSD and a SATA HDD.

I ran the following commands (to include flushing from buffers to measure the real time needed to write to each device).

NVME drive:

```
sudodus@bionic64 /mnt/sd1 $ time ( sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1M count=8000 status=progress ; sync )
7480541184 byte (7,5 GB, 7,0 GiB) kopierade, 4 s, 1,9 GB/s
8000+0 poster in
8000+0 poster ut
8388608000 byte (8,4 GB, 7,8 GiB) kopierade, 4,86151 s, 1,7 GB/s

real    0m9,243s
user    0m0,014s
sys 0m3,921s
```

SATA-SSD:

```
sudodus@bionic64 /tmp $ time ( sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1M count=8000 status=progress ; sync )
8384413696 byte (8,4 GB, 7,8 GiB) kopierade, 11 s, 762 MB/s
8000+0 poster in
8000+0 poster ut
8388608000 byte (8,4 GB, 7,8 GiB) kopierade, 11,0025 s, 762 MB/s

real    0m25,841s
user    0m0,023s
sys 0m3,894s
```

SATA-HDD:

```
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/test/test0/temp $ time ( sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1M count=8000 status=progress ; sync )
8296333312 byte (8,3 GB, 7,7 GiB) kopierade, 18 s, 461 MB/s
8000+0 poster in
8000+0 poster ut
8388608000 byte (8,4 GB, 7,8 GiB) kopierade, 18,3536 s, 457 MB/s

real    0m50,050s
user    0m0,024s
sys 0m3,566s
```

Calculation of speed:

```
$ bc
...
scale=0
8000/9.243
865
8000/25.841
309
8000/50.050
159
```

Summary of real write speed in MiB/s

```
NVME: 865
SSD:  309
HDD:  159
```

So the conclusion is that the write speed to the NVME and SSD drives is way lower than the theoretical one. We must conclude that there can be several bottlenecks that limit the speed, not only the device itself.

I would not blame `dd`, I think there are other bottlenecks. But it seems to me that your write speed 220 MiB/s is too low for your NVME SSD. (I suspect that you can discard your second result, 1.4GB/s, since it was only showing the write speed to RAM, but not including flushing the buffers.)

Maybe you can test the write speed to your NVME drive, when **booted live** from a few different **new** linux distros/versions. It is possible that a new linux kernel has faster drivers for you hardware.

By the way, what file system is there in your NVME drive? Linux works best with Linux filesystems (for example ext4).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add `oflag=direct` with `dd`, writes are buffered, throughputs are not real.

Comment: dd is not a correct tool to measure throughputs with any flags anyway